# C# WPF with CLR throw exception

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-c++, clr

I am creating WPF in Visual Studio 2015, I have a CLR class.

Just very straightforward, I open up Visual Studio 2015 and create the CLR (Class Library), and build it.
And then, I create a WPF Application, I added the CLR as a reference in my WPF project. I tried to build both projects in AnyCPU.

[image]

```
// TestCLR.h  
#pragma once

using namespace System;

namespace TestCLR {

    public ref class TestWrapper
    {
    public:
        TestWrapper() {}
        ~TestWrapper() {}

        // TODO: Add your methods for this class here.
    };
}


// TestCLR.cpp
// This is the main DLL file.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestCLR.h"
```

---

```
// in my MainWindow.xaml.cs
namespace TestWpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private TestWrapper test;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // when uncomment the following line, an exception is thrown
            test = new TestWrapper();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the WPF program, it throws an exception
[image]

Am I missing some critical info/settings for WPF that need to work with CLR?

Comment: Well it sounds like the TestWrapper constructor is throwing an exception. I suspect that the XamlParseException has an inner exception - you should inspect it.

Comment: (It would also be clearer if you'd just refer to class libraries, which is what I think you mean by "CLR" - WPF *always* runs on the CLR in normal terminology...)

Comment: my TestWrapper constructor is empty, by the way how to inspect XamlParseException? thanks.

Comment: Show the `TestWrapper();` class please

Comment: <agreeing and appending to John Skeets comment>... because CLR means Common Language Runtime, which is dot nets [virtual machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime), you should not use it as a term for Class Library. Good Terms for class libraries are "library" or "dll", ..

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain, edited my question with TestWrapper class

Comment: That's not your actual code - it wouldn't compile. And please provide source code as text rather than in screenshots. In terms of inspecting the exception - your debugger is suggesting you Break, so do that - you should then be able to see the exception.

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain, TestWrapper class can be build after `ref` and `public:` is removed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071577/does-a-clr-class-library-have-to-be-run-in-win32   this will help i guess.

Comment: Ah, so this is a C++ library? It would have been *really* useful to mention that much earlier on. But again, the exception is really where the most information will be,.

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain thanks, I noticed changing the TestWpf `Platform Target` to `x86` (in Project Properties -> Build) works, it does not throw an exception anymore, but I am building a 64-bit application, supposedly the Platform Target is x64 right?

Comment: @hghew yes but if you read that answer carefully you would notice that that they say "Changing the solution platform only affects the C++/CLI project, not the C# project. Right-click the C# project > Properties > Build tab to select the jitter you want to use. Untick the "Prefer 32-bit" checkbox for the x64 solution configuration. Again for the Release configuration."

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain, yupe, all this while have unticked Prefer 32-bit, just double-checked and it is, seems now the only way without throwing the exception is Platform Target to x86, am scratching my head too, actually, I have tested C# Windows Form without problem (with the CLR as well)

Comment: you may try : Build the CLR proj as x64 first and then your project as x64.If not then build CLR project as x86 and your C# as x64. One of this will work.

Comment: The debugger in VS2015 has a lot of bugs and quirks, it for one make the Exception Assistant unhelpful like this.  Use Tools > Options > Debugging > General, tick "Use Managed Compatibility Mode".

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, it is the wrong dll in my binary folder.
In TestWpf bin folder, I noticed the TestCLR.dll is not x64, it is x86, by putting the right platform dll, it does not throw an exception anymore.